# Android Studios getting a "Classifier 'id' does not have a companion object, and thus must be initialized here" in my program

Tags: android, kotlin

Im using an If/Else statement so that when the fields of the email and password are successfully filled out that it will send them to a page that says Welcome.

Heres the issue:
On the Else statement Im referring to the Buttons Id(createBtn) and continue to get a Classifier id does not have a companion object, and thus must be initialized here error.

Heres my code:

```
package com.example.lab10

import android.content.Intent
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import com.example.lab10.R.id
import com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_signup.*

class Signup : AppCompatActivity() {



    private lateinit var auth: FirebaseAuth

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_signup)

        auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()

createBtn.setOnClickListener {
    if (emailSignupId.text.trim().toString().isNotEmpty()
        || passwordSignupId.text.trim().toString().isNotEmpty()
    ) {

        createUser(emailSignupId.text.trim().toString(), passwordSignupId.text.trim().toString())
    } else {
        Snackbar.make(
            findViewById(R.id.createBtn), //HERES THE ISSUE
            "Check your username and password then try again", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG
        ).show()
    }
        }
    }
fun createUser(email: String, password: String) {
    auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
        .addOnCompleteListener(this) { task ->
            if (task.isSuccessful) {
                startActivity(Intent(this, Thankyou::class.java))
            } else {
                Snackbar.make(
                    findViewById(R.id createUser),
                    "Enter a valid username and password (6 characters)", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG
                ).show()
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the ID of the outermost layer of layout instead of the Button.

So in your **activity_signup.xml**, assume you have a LinearLayout, assign an ID to it:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    ...
</LinearLayout>
```

Then create a Snackbar using the above ID:

```kotlin
// Use view with findViewById<Your Layout Class>(R.id.<Your layout ID>)
Snackbar.make(
    findViewById<LinearLayout>(R.id.mainLayout),
    "Check your username and password then try again", 
    Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG
).show()
```